Generar reportes con cortes semanales en Apps Script
estoy realizando un script el cual genera un PDF con datos sobre un informe de Looker Studio donde el mismo se va enviando por cortes semanales es decir:

1/08/2024 al 7/08/2024
8/08/2024 al 15/08/2024
16/08/2024 al 23/08/2024
24/08/2024 al 31/08/2024

Luego se envían por mail, adjunto el codigo:
function exportarInformesSemanalesYEnviar() {
  // URL base del informe de Looker Studio
  var baseUrl = 'https://lookerstudio.google.com/reporting/a37583ed-3901-44c2-b9c8-e7657fcfae46';
  
  // Obtiene la fecha actual
  var hoy = new Date();
  var año = hoy.getFullYear();
  var mes = (hoy.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0'); // Obtiene el mes en formato MM
  
  // Obtiene el último día del mes actual
  var ultimoDiaMes = new Date(año, hoy.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
  
  // Configura los cortes semanales según el número de días del mes
  var cortes = [
    {inicio: año + '-' + mes + '-01', fin: año + '-' + mes + '-07'},
    {inicio: año + '-' + mes + '-08', fin: año + '-' + mes + '-15'},
    {inicio: año + '-' + mes + '-16', fin: año + '-' + mes + '-23'},
    {inicio: año + '-' + mes + '-24', fin: año + '-' + mes + '-' + ultimoDiaMes.toString().padStart(2, '0')}
  ];
  
  cortes.forEach(function(corte) {
    // Convertir las fechas de inicio y fin en objetos Date
    var fechaInicio = new Date(corte.inicio);
    var fechaFin = new Date(corte.fin);
    
    // Verificar si el período ya ha pasado
    if (fechaFin <= hoy) {
      // Generar la URL con los parámetros de fecha
      var reportUrl = baseUrl + '?start_date=' + corte.inicio + '&end_date=' + corte.fin + '&format=pdf';
      
      // Fetch del informe PDF
      var options = {
        'muteHttpExceptions': true,
        'headers': {
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
        }
      };
      
      // Aumenta el retraso para garantizar que el informe esté listo
      Utilities.sleep(3000); // Sleep for 3 seconds before fetching
      
      try {
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(reportUrl, options);
        
        // Verificar el código de respuesta HTTP antes de continuar
        if (response.getResponseCode() === 200) {
          var blob = response.getBlob().setName("Informe_Semanal_" + corte.inicio + "_al_" + corte.fin + ".pdf");
          
          // Log del tamaño del archivo PDF
          Logger.log('Tamaño del archivo PDF: ' + blob.getBytes().length + ' bytes');
          
          // Guardar el archivo en Google Drive para inspección
          var file = DriveApp.createFile(blob);
          Logger.log('Archivo guardado en Drive con ID: ' + file.getId());
    
          // Configurar el correo electrónico
          var destinatario = "valentino.decimetrica@gmail.com";
          var asunto = "Informe Semanal - " + corte.inicio + " al " + corte.fin;
          var cuerpo = "Adjunto encontrarás el informe semanal correspondiente al período del " + corte.inicio + " al " + corte.fin + ".";
    
          // Enviar el correo con el PDF adjunto
          MailApp.sendEmail({
            to: destinatario,
            subject: asunto,
            body: cuerpo,
            attachments: [blob]
          });
        } else {
          Logger.log('Error al obtener el informe: Código de respuesta HTTP ' + response.getResponseCode());
        }
      } catch (e) {
        Logger.log('Excepción al obtener el informe: ' + e.message);
      }
    } else {
      Logger.log('El período ' + corte.inicio + ' al ' + corte.fin + ' no ha pasado aún. No se generará informe.');
    }
  });
}

Pude comprobar que el archivo no se genera vacio y que no es un problema sobre el tiempo que se generan los reportes.
Ocurre al momento de descargar el PDF no se visualiza el contenido al parecer el archivo se genera dañado pero no identifico el error.

Intenta con DriveApp.create(name, content, mimeType)
